# How can we reset the configuaration in VS2008_C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

How can I reset the configuration parameter in VS2008 C++ 
I misconfigured my project

Comment: How about reverting to the previous version in your version control system? If you dont have that, I'd consider making a new project file.

Comment: There's more than one parameter, about a hundred or so.  Which one did you mess up?  I saw your hello world code, why don't you just start again with a new project?

Answer (score 1):

Create a new project file.

Close your solution, go to the directory where your solution lives and delete the `.vcproj` file(s).  You should also delete the `.sln` files, but if you have a very large solution with many projects and would find it unbearable to recreate all the projects, you can leave it intact.

Once the project file is deleted, you can construct a new one.  Either create a new solution from scratch, or if you have kept your solution then do *Add>NewProject*.  When you create a new project, you should select the option to create an Empty Project, so that it doesn't create any default source files for you.

Once you have created a blank project, you need to add your existing source code to the project.  You can do this simply by doing *Add>Existing Item...* and selecting every source file.